# how to parse urls correctly

Tags: go, url

When I want to parse my url I get the following error:

```
panic: parse "http://x:SmT2fH": invalid port ":SmT2fH" after host
```

This is how I parse it:

```
s := "http://x:S%40mT2fH#%25PVfTA5gjCtn@host:5432/default"

u, err := url.Parse(s)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

fmt.Println(u)
```

I expect `x` to be user and `S%40mT2fH#%25PVfTA5gjCtn` to be password.
But the errors say that it's an invalid port. because it's not port.

Does anyone know the problem?

Comment: I think that unencoded `#` makes that an invalid URL. If you rewrite that as `http://x:S%40mT2fH%23%25PVfTA5gjCtn@host:5432/default`, it seems to parse correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the literal `#` as it is "reserved" by URL for indicating the start of the fragment component.

The escape code is `%23`.

```golang
func main() {
    u, err := url.Parse("http://x:S%40mT2fH%23%25PVfTA5gjCtn@host:5432/default")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(u)
    fmt.Printf("%#v\n", u.User)
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/xMHX-gvqhqj